# SEDE search mashes together "X queries containing" multiline text

Tags: bug, design, search, data-explorer

[An example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=This+is+a+test+search+query).  If the search query is big enough so that it spans two lines, it blurs:

[image]

Can we free the bottom half of "containing" and add a bit more space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was probably only tested with a single word.

I've gone ahead and added a `line-height: 1.5em;` to the search-highlight class in site.css to give that a bit more space when it wraps under the word "containing".

The pull request is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/114). Allow for 6 to 8 weeks for merging and deploying.